# Download values of list from json file with 2 objects

Tags: c#, json, list, object, json-deserialization

I want to create simple game and i need to get values from json or change them.
I have 3 classes.

```
public class Person
{
    public string Specjality { get; set; }
    public int PWZ { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }
    public List<string> Items { get; set; }
}

public class Monster
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<string> Skills { get; set; }
}

public class Root
{
    public List<Person> people { get; set; }
    public List<Monster> monsters { get; set; }
}
```

**Json file**

```
{
  "Person": [
    {
      "Speciality": "Archer",
      "PWZ": 432742,
      "Name": "Charlie",
      "Surname": "Evans",
      "Items": [
        "Bow",
        "Arrow",
      ]
    },
    {
      "Speciality": "Soldier",
      "PWZ": 432534879,
      "Name": "Harry",
      "Surname": "Thomas",
      "Items": [
        "Gun",
        "Knife",
     ]
    }
  ],
  "Monster": [
    {
      "Name": "Papua",
      "Skills": [
        "Jump",
        "SlowWalk",
      ]
    },
    {
     "Name": "Geot",
      "Skills": [
        "Run",
        "Push",
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

My first problem is how to deserialize it, next how to print chosen values (for examples Skills of first Monster) on the screen and how to change some values (for example change "Jump" from Monster Skills to "Teleport" or change Name of Person). Thanks for all answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're very close.  To **deserialize** update the following:

1. Update/fix spelling/typo in `Person` class

   ```
   public string Speciality { get; set; }
   ```
2. Update `Root` property names (the names should match the Json):

   ```
   public class Root
   {
       public List<Person> Person { get; set; }
       public List<Monster> Monster { get; set; }
   }
   ```
3. Deserialize to `Root` class:

   ```
   var result = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Root>(json);
   ```

Now, there's also an issue with trailing commas in your Json string. I got this error:

> The JSON array contains a trailing comma at the end which is not
> supported in this mode. Change the reader options.

You can fix the Json string (remove the trailing commas in the arrays), or if you're using System.Text.Json to deserialize you can apply the `AllowTrailingCommas` option:

```
var options = new JsonSerializerOptions { AllowTrailingCommas = true };
var result = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Root>(json, options);
```

To **display** the values:

```
// iterate over Person/Monster collection
foreach (var person in result.Person)
    Console.WriteLine($"Name: {person.Name}, Items: {string.Join(", ", person.Items)}");

foreach (var monster in result.Monster)
    Console.WriteLine($"Name: {monster.Name}, Skills: {string.Join(", ", monster.Skills)}");
```

To **modify** an item you would just modify the `Person` or `Monster` instance, then serialize again:

```
// update name:
result.Person[0].Name = "Alan";
// serialize if you need to:
string json = JsonSerializer.Serialize(result);
```

Comment: Do you know, how can i print some value in the console? For example Skills of Monster Geot ? Or How can i change some values?

Comment: @Ebosin I just updated answer with display info.

Comment: thanks. Do you know how can i change some value?

Comment: Yes, I've just added how to modify a property to the answer too.  You just modify the property you want to change then re-serialize to json string. @Ebosin